# Git - print files mixed in different encoding

Tags: linux, git, iconv

I am working on a project whose files are different in encoding.(My OS is centos 7)

For example, `$SRC/a.cpp` may encoded in UTF-8, while `$SRC/b.cpp` is encoded in GB 2312(simplified Chinese).

Now if I enter `git diff`, the content will not display properly due to the mixed encoding.

I've tried `iconv` like this

```
git diff HEAD~1 | iconv -f gb2312 -t utf8 | less
```

It works well if all the files involved are encoded in GB 2312. But if any UTF-8 file is mixed, then iconv will broke like this

```
some well displayed UTF-8 text
...
iconv: illegal input sequence at position 120
```

My question is that if it is possible to make commands like `git diff` work properly without changing the file itself? I hope there can be some scripts filtering non-UTF-8 file for `iconv` or some `git` confiuration that can run `iconv` for non-UTF-8 file only.

**Edit**: The client of this project requests some files to have specific encodings and wants as less changes as possible for stability, so modifying files' encoding directly is not possible. A workaround without modifying the project is prefer.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use UTF-8 encoding for all files?

Comment: @Bodo Yes, changing file encoding is the most straightforward way in my position. But sadly, this project's client requests other files like python script and xml file to be encoded in a given encoding, which is not utf8. So I can not avoid mixing files with different encodings.

Comment: Do they really need the files to have a specific encoding *in Git*? You could have the files encoded as UTF-8 in Git and change the encoding when building / preparing the software. All additional information should be part of the question. You can [edit] the question.

Comment: @Bodo Your suggestion provide another perspective. The client does request some files to have a specific encoding. Actually it is a to b bussiness so wired request from the client is quite common. Same reason, changes encoding is hard to push, because it means modifying the whole project. Besides, some git GUI tools can handle different encodings well, so it is hard to convince the client. And that's the reason why I am searching for a workaround to make git works properly in cli without changing file's encoding. I will add these details to the question, thank you for reminding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need a [`git config` diff driver](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-diffltdrivergtcommand)

That driver script would first identify the encoding of each file and then convert it to UTF-8 if necessary before showing the diff.

Create a shell script (for instance `git-diff-encoding.sh`, with `chmod +x git-diff-encoding.sh`) which identifies the encoding of the files and then converts them to UTF-8 if necessary before showing the diff.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

FILE1="path/to/file1"
FILE2="path/to/file2"

# Identify encoding of the files using file command
ENC1=$(file -bi "$FILE1" | awk -F charset= '{print $2}')
ENC2=$(file -bi "$FILE2" | awk -F charset= '{print $2}')

# Convert files to UTF-8 if necessary
[ "$ENC1" != "utf-8" ] && iconv -f "$ENC1" -t utf-8 "$FILE1" -o "$FILE1".utf8
[ "$ENC2" != "utf-8" ] && iconv -f "$ENC2" -t utf-8 "$FILE2" -o "$FILE2".utf8

# Run git diff with potentially converted files
git diff --no-index "${FILE1}${ENC1:+.utf8}" "${FILE2}${ENC2:+.utf8}"
```

In your `.git/config` file, add the following lines to define a new diff driver called "encoding":

```
[diff "encoding"]
    command = /path/to/your/git-diff-encoding.sh
```

Tell Git which files should be handled by this new diff driver. You can do this in your repository's `.gitattributes` file (create it, if it does not exist, at the root folder of your Git repository). Add lines specifying the files to be handled by your new diff driver, for example:

```
*.cpp diff=encoding
```

Now, git will use your custom diff script when running `git diff` for files matching the patterns specified in the `.gitattributes` file.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply. I've tried it for the project and it seems like the bash script exists some corner cases that crash the diff. Anyway now I know what to do. I believe they can be fixed by myself and my problem can be solved then.

Comment: @Lotus Great! Don't forget to post an answer when you will have solved it!